# Custom extension file not opening in my app

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, file-type

I wanted a custom extension file (*.xyz) to be opened through my app. Inside the application manifest file I am writing the following:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"    android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz" />
        <data android:scheme="https"   android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz" />
        <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz" />
         <data android:scheme="file"   android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz" />
</intent-filter>
```

After that I will install my application on the device and will send a mail containing the `Sample.xyz` mail as an attachment. When I try to tap on attachment in the mail client to open the attachment then it will give an error called

`No app can open this attachment for viewing`

Even if when I download the attachment and then try to open it then it will give an error

`Can't open file`

Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong ?

Comment: Try to add another category first: <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

Comment: Can you try this:  `<data android:scheme="content" android:host="*" android:mimeType="application/xyz" />`?

Comment: @ManishMulimani What does **android:mimeType="application/xyz"** do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your filter does not match as it is not http https file and content at the same time - you will need different `<intent-filter>`'s for this - have a look here:
https://github.com/ligi/PassAndroid/blob/master/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
and just do what I do for *.pkpass for *.xyz like so:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz"
            android:scheme="file" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz"
            android:scheme="content" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I have added the intent filter just the way you have indicated plus I have also added the `mimeType` which was missing from your answer. still I am getting the following error in my logcat 'resolveIntent failed: found match, but none with CATEGORY_DEFAULT
Unable to find supporting activity. mime-type: application/xyz, uri: content://com.google.android.email.attachmentprovider/4/941/RAW, normalized mime-type: application/xyz normalized uri: content://com.google.android.email.attachmentprovider/4/941/RAW
resolveIntent failed: found match, but none with CATEGORY_DEFAULT
`

Comment: I did not do mime-type in this example as you did not do it in your original question - thought you have no specific mime-type for your use-case. This code works for me and a lot of users - can you please show how you adapted it? Do you get that message when you click e.g. on the mail attachment?

Comment: Yes I am getting this message when I am tapping on the mail attachment

Comment: Does it also fail when you click on a link in the browser? Please show your manifest! PS: Intent-Intercept is a nice tool to debug problems like this.

Comment: <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>                    
          <data
              android:host="*"
                  android:mimeType="application/tap"      
              android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz"
              android:scheme="content" />
      </intent-filter>

Comment: check with intent-intercept if application/tap is set as a mime-type in your case

Comment: Actually it is `application/xyz` only.

Comment: so application/tap will not match